# Bat file that extracts subtitle file then hard encodes the subtitle file into the original mkv file

Tags: batch-file, encoding, ffmpeg, mkv

My tv can play `mkv` files off of a flash drive but it cannot detect the subtitles files. I am trying to make a `bat` file that essentially takes the `.srt` file out of the `mkv` file then hard encodes it into the mkv file using ffmpeg. I am getting close but the naming is not working properly. For instance when it creates the subtitle file it names it `infile.mkv.srt`. When the file is encoded it is named `infile.mkvEncoded.mkv`. I am trying to get rid of the extra .mkv

I am not great with variables in bat files so I am not exactly sure what to do. I added the "Encoded" part to the name of the file so that it doesn't overwrite the original infile. I plan on just using bulk rename utility to get rid of that part unless there is a better way.

My code is:

```
    DO (
    MKDIR Encoded_Files
    )
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mkv') DO (
        ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vn -an -codec:s:0.1 srt "%%G.srt"
        ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vf "subtitles=%%G.srt" "%%GConverted"
        move *"%%~nG" "Encoded_Files"
            )
```

The expected result would be `infileEncoded.mkv*`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: You are looking for [`%%~nG`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Anyway, your code sample is not complete (there is an orphaned `do`); please read this: [mcve]...

Comment: No need to extract the subtitles first: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=input.mkv -c:a copy output.mkv`